# Confused about behavior of type aliases

Tags: go, types

Consider the following code (also on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RnJ4XCGlFnq)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type dur struct {
    time.Duration
}

type durWithMethods dur

type durWithoutMethods time.Duration

func main() {
    var d durWithMethods // works ??
    fmt.Println(d.String())
    
    var dWM durWithoutMethods
    fmt.Println(dWM.String()) // doesn't compile
}
```

I don't understand why the direct alias of `time.Duration` does not inherit any methods. Is it because `time.Duration` is an alias of a raw type?

Comment: 1. That's not a type alias. That's a simple type delcaration. 2. There is no inheritence in Go at all. Full stop. But if you _embed_, as you did in the case of `dur`, then you can access the embedded type's methods.

Comment: I don't know why two people chose to downvote your question. But asking for vote explanations really isn't appropriate, since votes are intentionally anonymous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Type declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) come in two forms: alias declarations and type definitions.

Type definition creates a new type and strips all methods. Type alias "just" creates (binds) a new identifier to the same type. Using the "original" name or the new name is identical.

Your first example:

```
type durWithMethods dur
```

This creates a new type `durWithMethods` that will have `dur` as its underlying type. Since the underlying type is a struct which embeds `time.Duration`, methods of the embedded type gets promoted and will be part of the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the embedder type, thus `dur` and also `durWithMethods`. `Duration.String()` will get promoted regardless of creating a new type, because this `String()` method is not a method of `dur` but that of `time.Duration`.

When you write `d.String()`, it will be a shorthand for `d.Duration.String()`.

The second example:

```
type durWithoutMethods time.Duration
```

Creates a new type `durWithoutMethods` which again strips all methods. Since `Duration.String()` was a method of `time.Duration`, it will not be a method of `durWithoutMethods`.

A real type alias would look like this:

```
type sameAsDuration = time.Duration
```

And since it denotes the same type it also has the `String()` method:

```
var sad sameAsDuration
fmt.Println(sad.String()) // works
```