# Is a type that extends a Map still passed by reference in Go?

Tags: go

If you have a type in Go, that extends a Map, is this new type still "passed by reference" (or respectively passed as a pointer value)? Or is it copied when used as a function parameter?

Example:

```golang
type myMapType map[string][]int

func doSomething(m myMapType) myMapType{

// do something
return m
}
```

I want to prevent unnecessary copying of data. So do I need a pointer for the above example, or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no "extends" in Go. And no pointer is needed, passing `myMapType` will share the backing map structure, which you can easily check by adding an entry to `m` inside `doSomething()` and printing the passed map after the call outside (the original, not the returned value).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What is this concept (that you make a type "on top" of another type) then called in go?

Comment: It's a [type definition](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_declarations). Also see: [Confused about behavior of type aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988768/confused-about-behavior-of-type-aliases/64988906#64988906)

Comment: Okay I see, that makes it clear to me, thank you again! Don't you want to post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare

```golang
type myMapType map[string][]int
```

You now have a type called `myMapType`, whose behaviour is the same as `map[string][]int`.

It's the same as if every instance of `myMapType` was an instance of `map[string][]int`, with the only difference being that their types are not considered "the same" in cases where that matters (assignment, type switch, type assertion, etc.).

In other words, `myMapType` and `map[string][]int` are **equi-valent** but not **identic-al**.

Comment: I'd say that «whose behaviour is the same» is a bit of a stretch as `type B A` does not make B inherit the method set of A if that has one. A `map` does not have methods so this does not apply but in general, it does. So maybe a more to-the-point phrasing would be that after `type B A` values of both types have identical memory layouts/representations.