# Assigning to type definition using reflection in Go

Tags: go, reflection, type-alias

I have setup a type called `Provider` that defines an integer:

```
type Provider int

func (enum *Provider) Scan(raw interface{}) error {
    *enum = Provider(int(raw))
}
```

If I create an object, Foo, with a `Provider` field, like this:

```
type Foo struct {
    Code Provider
    Value string
}

foo := &Foo {
    Code:  Provider(0),
    Value: "derp",
}

var scnr sql.Scanner
scannerType := reflect.TypeOf(&scnr).Elem()

tType := reflect.TypeOf(foo)
tField := tType.Field(0)
fmt.Printf("Field %s, of type %s, kind %s\n", 
    tField.Name, tField.Type, tField.Type.Kind())
```

When I run this code, I get that the field is of type `Provider` and its Kind is `int`. However, I cannot assign an int to a Provider using reflection because this will fail:

```
getInteger() interface{} {
    return 1
}

fValue := reflect.ValueOf(foo).Elem()
vField := fValue.Field(0)
vField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(getInteger())) // panic: reflect.Set: value of type int is not assignable to type Provider
```

The normal solution to this would be to do `reflect.ValueOf(Provider(getInteger().(int)))`, however, this won't work because `vField` is set inside of a loop that iterates over a structure's fields and therefore will have a different type. Essentially, I would like a way to detect that `vField` is a definition of `int` (ie. `Provider`) rather than an `int`, itself; so I could use reflection to cast the integer value to `Provider` when I set it.

Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: `type Provider int` is **not** an alias.

Comment: @Volker I'm sure you're correct but I don't remember the proper term, and the Go documentation that explains the actual term is difficult to find. And, since you're correcting me, I can assume that my meaning came across just fine.

Comment: "the Go documentation that explains the actual term is difficult to find" Difficult in what sense? It's the first sentence about type declarations in the language specification https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_declarations .

Comment: @Volker Difficult to find as in, if I didn't know that it was on that page I wouldn't be able to find it with a Google search.

Comment: @Volker Also, that document doesn't make clear the difference in terminology between a "normal" type definition, `type A struct { ... }`; and one that aliases another type, `type A int`, for example.

Comment: @Volker Nevermind, I was confusing the C-language version of the term with the Go version of the term. `type A struct { ... }` is a declaration, not a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the `Convert` function in conjunction with the `Assignable` function to do my check:

```
// Get value to assign and its type
vValue := reflect.ValueOf(getInteger())
tValue := vValue.Type()

// Check if the field can be assigned the value; if it can then do so
// Otherwise, check if a conversion can be assigned
vType := vField.Type()
if tValue.AssignableTo(vType) {
    vField.Set(vValue)
} else if vValue.CanConvert(vType) {
    vField.Set(vValue.Convert(vType))
}
```

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4):

The *kind* and *type* are not identical terms. *Kind* of both `int` and `Provider` is `int` because `Provider` has `int` as its underlying type. But the type `Provider` is not identical to `int`. What you have is a [type definition](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_declarations), but not a type alias! Those are 2 different things. See [Confused about behavior of type aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988768/confused-about-behavior-of-type-aliases/64988906#64988906) for details.

The type of `Foo.Code` field is `Provider`, you can only [assign](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) a value of type `Provider` to it:

```
vField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(Provider(1)))
```

This works.

Note that reflection or not, you can't assign `int` to `Foo.Code`:

```
var i int = 3
var foo Foo
foo.Code = i // Error!
```

The above has compile time error:

> error: cannot use i (variable of type int) as type Provider in assignment

What may be confusing is that using a constant works:

```
var foo Foo
foo.Code = 3 // Works!
```

This is because `3` is an untyped constant representable by a value of type `Provider`, so the constant will be converted to `Provider`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think my original question might've been a bit too abstract. I don't have an integer constant, I have another value that I need to convert to a `Provider` object.

Comment: If you have a value of type `int`, use conversion, e.g. `vField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(Provider(intValue)))`

Comment: I have a `reflect.Value` that holds an `int`.

Comment: If you have the `int` value wrapped in an interface, use type assertion first: `vField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(Provider(wrappedIntValue.(int))))`

Comment: I ended up using `Convert` as the actual code surrounding that value is more complicated than I am willing to express in an SO question.

Comment: The answer I wrote fixed my specific problem but your answer contains the better response overall.